# MS Excel convert cell matrix (1x15 -> 3x5)

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

What is the formula for displaying cells in a 3 cell increment at a time, like  A1, A4, A7, A10?

Moreover, would it be possible to transform below a list (1x15) of data into a table(3x5). Thanks.

PS. The original data is in A1-A15. I want it displayed in B1:D5 (a 3x5 view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=OFFSET($A$1,COLUMN()-2+ROW()*3-3,0)
```

Place it in cells B1:D5